# Image from folder not appearing

Tags: swift, xcode, skspritenode

Just getting started with Swift in XCode and I've run through a number of tutorials.  Unfortunately they haven't covered some essential basics.  I've already imported a directory of assets (which contains subdirectories) and selected "Copy (as needed)".  The folder is blue and appears in the Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources.  I've used the simple lines below but the image still appears as a red "X" in the simulator.  I have done a clean/build/restart and it's still not working.

```
    if let ship = SKSpriteNode(fileNamed: "cannon.png")
    {
        ship.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
        self.addChild(ship)
    }
```

The referenced file is located in `Assets/Sprite Images/cannon.png`

How can I get the image to appear?

**EDIT**

I had downloaded the [Space Invaders Tutorial Starter Project](https://www.raywenderlich.com/124005/make-game-like-space-invaders-sprite-kit-swift-tutorial-part-1) and it uses the idea of an "Assets" folder and does precisely what I've attempted.  There is nothing listed in the "Images.xcassets" folder so I'm not sure why mine isn't loading.  Do I need to identify this as a specific folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "myImage.png")
let ship = SKSpriteNode.init(texture: texture)
```

OR

`let spaceship = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "myImage.png")`

In either case, use `imageNamed`

Comment: Same results.  I also verified that that file has the name "cannon.png" in the file inspector under "Identity and Type"

Comment: Assuming you are clicking on the .xcassets (blue folder), under "Identity and type" should be something like "Assets.xcassets" or the name of your xcasset. Clicking on an asset in the .xcassets then under "Attributes" should have the name of the image.

Comment: Ah i was clicking on the actual file in the directory structure in the Project Navigator

Comment: Yes, you need to use the name of the image as it appears in the .xcassets resource.

Comment: Interesting because it's not listed there.   I'll investigate.  Thanks.

Comment: you can simply drag the file to the .xcassets folder to add it

Comment: Please see my comment regarding the sample project I had downloaded which seems to use the same manner of loading that I'm attempting.

Comment: The project you linked to does not use .xcassets so you just need to make sure the image file has been added to your Target.  You can check this in the File Inspector (right sidebar)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to add this as a bundle resource in order to make it available.  I did this by selecting the top level solution and went to the following area: Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources

At the bottom is a +/- and you can add the individual items to the project.  After adding you will select "Copy (as needed)" and the item will appear in the list.  It then becomes available to the project.  Adding it at the directory level did not work unfortunately.

As is indicated in other searches it seems common to have to check the box for "Target Membership" in the File Inspector but even after this I do not have the checkbox available.

For what it's worth it appears a combination of the above solves the problem.